# Problem with firebase auth kotlin library version 21.0.4

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, firebase-authentication

When I update the com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx library to a version higher than 21.0.1 I get the following warning:

> Kotlin library {0} was compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin.

[image]

I already tried to update the Kotlin plugin in tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates, but it didn't work. I have the latest version of Kotlin plugin and Android Studio installed. How can I solve this problem, or just hide the warning?

Comment: Hello, which Kotlin version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using kotlin 1.4.32.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update the Kotlin version in your build.gradle **Project level file**, you will find a "plugins" ids, try to set it to 1.6.21 (I have it on 1.6.10):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

Comment: I didn't find the plugin versions as you wrote, so I set this line ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.21". But after that I got another error: Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Did Gradle synchronised?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete Gradle.build Project level file?

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: First thing I notice is you have the old Gradle config, but shouldn’t be an issue. I see jcenter() there, jcenter is no longer supported, can you replace jcenter() with mavenCentral() and try again?

Comment: I replaced jcenter() with mavenCentral() but that didn't help me.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches and restarting? Just to discard

Comment: I did it, but the error didn't go away. Here is my build.gradle file:buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: I have worked with this library, but never had/heard this issue… I hope someone else can help…

Comment: Btw your Gradle.build is ok